# Want to eliminate "Document or link" dialog on File/Save

Tags: office, save

I have a default Document Library in SharePoint.  When my users save documents (Word, Excel, PPT) to this document library, they get a dialog asking if they want to save a "Document" or a "Link to a document".  I would like my users to save the actual documents in this library in all cases.  Is there a way to stop SharePoint from prompting users on this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the `Link to a Document` content type from the Library settings.